# Grub not showing up after ubuntu server 20.04 fresh install

Tags: boot, grub2, dell, raid, mbr

I just can't get Grub working ! Grub is not even showing up (screen keeps black and nothing happens).
I was able to start the system with *super grub* and I changed this in /etc/default/grub :

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="**quiet splash nomodeset** keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=fr keyboard-configuration/variantcode=oss"
>
> **GRUB_TERMINAL=console**

*update-grub* runs without reporting any errors.

I also made a **report with boot repair** available here https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hpDtHKnmvD/ , but boot repair does not suggest any solution.

My computer is an old **Dell power edge T300** without UEFI, and the OS is installed in raid 1 partition made with mdadm.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With BIOS & gpt partitioned drives, you need a bios_grub partition for grub to correctly install & boot.

You can create the tiny 1 or 2MB unformatted partition with bios_grub flag if using gparted/parted or use code ef02 if using gdisk to create it. It can be anywhere within the first 2TiB of your drive. Do not really know RAID, but you probably need it on both drives. & maybe grub on both drives.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_boot_partition

http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/

Comment: Well, there already was a bios grub partition (automatically created by Ubuntu installer) so I guessed it was on the wrong disk... And I was right ! After switching disk cable, it was OK. Thanks a lot, you put me on the right track!

Comment: Often drive order is set by BIOS when system is booted, so sda may become sdb or vice-versa. That is why fstab now uses UUIDs which do not change. But grub may not see change and need to be on both drives.

Comment: OK thanks for pointing this out. I remember I already faced this problem and I did not understand why I my server failed to boot sometime and sometime not... I did install boot partition on both drive and it now works like a charm even if a disk is missing. Thanks again !